# Solr (Sunspot) conditional order_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails

I use `Solr sunspot` gem in my Rails app. What I have now: `order_by(:some_time, :desc)`. What I need to do is:

If `:some time` column value is within last hour then all records with this condition are ordered by `:status` column otherwise ordered by `:some_time`

I didn't find anything similar in the docs and I am not sure what is a good way to implement this.

PS: I tried to  do grouping and ordering after solr search is finished, but it looks heavy and I believe things should be consistent, so if there is any chance to do it with solr, I would like to go for it.

Comment: e.g. if results have 100 records and 25 of them satisfy the condition, then do you want 25 to be sorted by `status` and rest by `sometime` or all records sorted by `status`?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon if 25 of them satisfy the condition (`:some_time > Time.now - 1.hour`) then order by `:status` & `:some_time`, all other by `:some_time` only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sunspot gem will let you say [`order_by_function`](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#ordering) to use Solr's [functional ordering ability](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) (look for "Search by Function"). So it looks to me like you could do this or something like it (not tested):

```
order_by_function(:map, [:ms, [:NOW, :some_date], '0', '3600000', '0'], :status)
```

In other words: find the age in milliseconds of the document, and anything within 1 hour "flatten" to 0 (so they are all tied). Break ties by sorting by status. Seems like that should work, right?